# Get user or user_id Soundcloud api

Tags: api, get, soundcloud

I'm making a website for a friend who's a DJ. He posts his music on Soundcloud. I am trying to get his music via the Soundcloud api on his website. The problem is, I don't know how to get or select a user with the soundcloud api. With the code I have I can search music by query or genre, but not by user.

```
function play(){

SC.initialize({      
client_id: 'His client, not het user_id'

});

SC.get('/tracks', { q: music},
function(tracks) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15);
  var track_url = tracks[random].permalink_url;
  SC.oEmbed(track_url, {auto_play: true, color: "ff0066"},
    document.getElementById("target"));
  }
);

}`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for a specific users tracks using the `/users/:user_id/tracks` endpoint. For example, for a user with the user_id `293`, you can retrieve their tracks with the following code example:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'CLIENT_ID'
});

SC.get('/users/293/tracks', function(tracks) {
  ...
});
```

If you don't know their `user_id`, but have their permalink url, you can use the `/resolve` endpoint to retrieve it:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'CLIENT_ID'
});

SC.get('/resolve', {
  url: 'https://soundcloud.com/paulosman'
}, function(user) {
  console.log(user.id);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @PaulOsman, can you please have a look at my question about soundcloud? here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20151449/oauth-2-0-user-signup-waiting-for-activation